# Is it possible to change order of transactions in block and send them to validators individually?

Tags: consensus, dpos

After a block producer executes the transactions and form a block, in the process of broadcasting it to the network for validation by validators(remaining 20 block producers), is it possible to make changes in the block by block producer and send unidentical blocks to validators?
Question in Detail:
Say, a block is having transactions in order as “t1,t2,t3,…,tn-1 and tn” which are executed by a scheduled block producer – “Block_Producer-A” and the order of execution of transactions are t1,t2,t3,…,tn-1 and tn.
Now, the duty of the block producer - “Block_Producer-A” is to broadcast it for validation.
Then, is it possible for a block producer - “Block_Producer-A” to send the block just by changing the order of transactions to each validator?
That means, (represented below is an assumed case)

•   “Block_Producer-A” sends a block to “Block_Producer-B”(Validator) with the order of transactions as “t1,t2,t3,…,tn-1 and tn” .

•   “Block_Producer-A” sends a block to “Block_Producer-C”(Validator) by changing the order of transactions from “t1,t2,t3,…,tn-1 and tn”  to “t3,t2,t1,…,tn and tn-1”.

•   “Block_Producer-A” sends a block to “Block_Producer-D”(Validator) by changing the order of transactions from “t1,t2,t3,…,tn-1 and tn”  to “t9,t10,t2,…,tn-2 and tn-1”.

•   .

•   .

•   .

•   .

•   .

•   “Block_Producer-A” sends a block to “Block_Producer-U”(Validator) by changing the order of transactions from “t1,t2,t3,…,tn-1 and tn”  to “t1,t10,t3,…,tn and tn-2”.

Answer (score 1):

No. Block-hash/digest (SHA-256) changes, when order of transactions changes.